# Powershell GUI, Calling specific property from Active Directory from ListView

Tags: wpf, powershell

I am creating a PowerShell gui that I am using to remove computers from Active Directory.

I was able to get the list view to populate the computer name, OU path, and IP address.

However when I am creating the script to delete the object, I am running into an issue.

I would like the user to be able to select the computer object from the list view and press delete.

However using SelectedItems grabs all 3 properties (Name, OU path, and IP address).

Output being:
@{Name=COMPUTER; DistinguishedName=CN=xx,OU=xx,OU=xx,OU=xx,OU=xx,OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx; IPv4Address=xx.xx.xx.xx}

How would I have it so that SelectedItems will only grab the computer name so I can pass it into a variable that can be used with Remove-ADComputer?

I apologize for any formatting issues. I am very new at this.

XML:

```html
<Window x:Class="SCCMAD.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SCCMAD"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SCCMAD" Height="353.176" Width="586.987">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,-31" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="577" Height="353" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="Input" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="50,86,129,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Type Device Name here..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="398" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.501,0.522"/>
        <Label x:Name="secondTitle" Content="Tool used for removal of devices from SCCM and/or AD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="324" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <ListView x:Name="Grid" Margin="49,114,46,133" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding Name}" Width="120"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Distinguished Name" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding DistinguishedName}" Width="120"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="IP Address" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding IPv4Address}" Width="120"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="OK" Content="OK" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="163,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" Height="23"/>
        <Button x:Name="SCCM" Content="SCCM" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,256,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="Both" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Both" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="254,256,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="AD" Content="AD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Column="1" Margin="89,256,0,0"/>
        <Label Content="Remove from:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,225,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <StatusBar x:Name="StatusBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="0,290,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="577" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Powershell:

```js
Function Get-ADDevice {
param($computername =$env:COMPUTERNAME) 
    Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -like '$computername*'" -Properties Name, DistinguishedName, IPv4Address | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName, IPv4Address
}
$WPFOK.Add_Click({
    try
    {
        $WPFGrid.Clear()
        Get-ADDevice -computername $WPFInput.Text | % {$WPFGrid.AddChild($_)}
    }
    catch
    {
        $WPFStatusBar.Text = $_.Exception.Message
    }
}) 
$WPFAD.Add_Click({
    foreach($item in $WPFGrid.SelectedItems)
    { 
        Write-Host $item
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. How about `Write-Host $item.Name` ?

Comment: @Theo If it's a WPF GUI (it is), then the user doesn't see the console host.  He would need to select the property needed to display in the list.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It looks like the OP is using `Write-Host` in lieu of `Remove-ADComputer` in the example script that he posted. I believe Theo was just suggesting referencing the `.Name` property, rather than the entire object.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician gotcha.  that makes sense.  In this case, the OP is seeing the string representation of their object which is displaying the extra properties.  Being selective about the property displayed would resolve the issue.

Comment: @Theo Looks like using that property was able to single out the name but still keep the functionality of the listview being able to display OU and IP address. Thanks!